# Inserir palavra acentuada no MYSQL

Tags: java, html, mysql, servlet, utf-8

Como consigo inserir corretamente palavras com acento no MySQL? Exemplo: se tento inserir "João" está gravando Joã£o.

MySQL está como `Collation utf8-default collation`

Eu pego os dados do input "nome"abaixo:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8" />
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <title>Cadastro</title>
    </head>
.
.
.
form class="form-horizontal" action='Cadastro' method="POST">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Cadastro de Operador</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="idNome">Nome</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="idNome" name="idNome" type="text" placeholder="Nome do operador" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>
.
.
.
```

Servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String nome = request.getParameter("idNome");
        String mail = request.getParameter("idDepto");
        int re = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idUsuario"));
        String senha = request.getParameter("idSenha");
        int nivel = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idAdmin"));//1=adm     2=user

        System.out.println(nome);
        Funcionario f = new Funcionario(re,nome);
        Login l = new Login(f,senha,mail,nivel);

        FuncionarioDAO fd = new FuncionarioDAO();

        LoginDAO ld = new LoginDAO();

        try {
            fd.create(f);
            ld.create(f, senha, mail, nivel);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Cadastro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        processRequest(request, response);
    }
```

Funcionario DAO:

```
  public void create(Funcionario e)throws Exception{  

      //**********************
      try {
            java.sql.Connection conexao = getConexao();
            PreparedStatement pstm = (PreparedStatement) conexao.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO funcionario(re,nome) VALUES(?,?)");
            pstm.setInt(1,e.getRe());  
                        pstm.setString(2,e.getNome());
                        //pstm.setString(3,e.getEsc().getNome());


            pstm.execute();
            pstm.close();
            conexao.close();
        } catch (SQLException o) {
            o.printStackTrace();
        }


   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente adicionar antes da query esta outra query:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Se isso funcionar, o charset do seu banco não foi configurado corretamente. Verifique se o charset está  realmente configurado como utf8 (apenas **"utf8"**).

No entanto, se os caracteres estranhos já etiverem aparecendo antes mesmo da inserção, você precisa definir o encoding do request:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
```

Comment: Mas se eu imprimir a palavra no lá no Servlet com System.out.println(nome); ela já imprime no console com caracteres estranhos, então o problema não seria antes do MySQL?

Comment: Antes de inserir o campo já está com caracteres estranhos?

Comment: Se sim, você precisa definir o encoding do request: request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")

Comment: Muito obrigado! Era o request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") que estava faltando mesmo.